# replacing spaces with chars

Tags: php, html

```
$subject = "Keep your    spacing   perfect!";
```

Print out `$subject` where replace any two spaces in a row '' with a `-` and any single space '' with a * so the example above prints:
`Keep*your--spacing-*perfect!`

**NOTE: there are four spaces in between "your" and "spacing" so there will be only two dashes and there will be three asterisks in between "spacing" and "perfect" and only one in between "keep" and "your".

Im having  hard time with this question and I would like some help with this please

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried thus far? Show us your code and let's see how we can help.

Comment: *would have to be 3 asterisks* - I don't see 3 `*` in your output

Comment: ya i made a mistake when typing sorry.

Comment: should not it be `Keep*your--spacing***perfect!` ?

Comment: *and there will be three asterisks in between "spacing" and "perfect"* - again, what 3 asterisks? you have confused the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), you can use `arrays` to specify what to replace and the replacement, i.e.:

```
$subject = "Keep your    spacing   perfect!";
$subject = str_replace(array("  ", " "), array("-", "*"), $subject);
# Keep*your--spacing-*perfect!
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/Kk67Pu)

Answer (score 0):

Replace first the double spaces, and then replace the single spaces in the result:

```
$subject = "Keep your    spacing   perfect!";
$subject = str_replace("  ", "-", $subject);
$subject = str_replace(" ", "*", $subject);
echo $subject;
```